# Redux saga channel blocking inconsistently

Tags: javascript, redux-saga, saga

I have a redux saga setup where for some reason my `channel` blocks when I'm trying to `take` from it and I can't work out why.

I have a `PubSub` mechanism which subscribes to an event and when received calls this function:

```
const sendRoundEnd = (msg, data) => {
  console.log('putting round end')
  roundEndChannel.put({
    type: RUN_ENDED,
    data: data.payload
  })
}
```

I have a watcher for this channel defined like this:

```
function* watchRoundEndChannel() {
  while(true) {
    console.log('before take')
    const action = yield take(roundEndChannel)
    console.log('after take')
    yield put(action)
  }
}
```

And I have a reducer setup which is listening for the `put` of `RUN_ENDED` like this:

```
case RUN_ENDED:
  console.log(action)
  return {
    ...state,
    isRunning: false,
    roundResult: action.data
  }
```

Finally, I have a `roundEndChannel` const within the file (but not within the functions) and I export the following function as part of an array which is fed into `yield all[]`:

`takeEvery(roundEndChannel, watchRoundEndChannel)`

So if my understanding is right, when I get the msg from my pubsub I should first hit `sendRoundEnd` which puts to `roundEndChannel` which should in turn put the `RUN_ENDED` action.

What's weird however is that when I run these functions and receive the message from the pubsub, the following is logged:

```
putting round end
before take
```

I never get to the `after take` which suggests to me that the channel doesn't have anything in it, but I'm pretty sure that isn't the case as it should have been `put` to in the event handler of the pubsub immediately prior.

It feels like I'm missing something simple here, does anyone have any ideas (or ways I can examine the channel at different points to see what's in there?)

Answer (score 0):

Arg, managed to fix this. The problem was I had exported the `watchRoundEndChannel` wrapped in a `takeEvery` which was snatching my pushed events up.

I exported the function like this `fork(watchRoundEndChannel)` and things work as I expected.